# Do something if all the criteria are true

Tags: c, if-statement

In my study I have to program a system that get struct of Apartments that contain: apartment code, price, number of rooms and etc.

In other part of the system when the List of apartments are including apartments,
I have to build a function that print out to screen all of the apartments that meet all the requirements the user asking for. for example, for this command from user: "PRINT maxRooms 5 Price 20000" the function will scan the List of apartments and print only the apartments that have maximum 5 rooms and their price is less than 20000.

I've initialize those local variables in -1 and now I'm in the stage that if my local variable different from -1 the user asked for this filter.
For the sake of simplicity lets assume that we have only three criteria: price, maximum number of rooms, minimum number of rooms.

I'm trying to avoid this situation:

```
#define UNDEFINED_FILLTER -1
while (currentAprt != NULL)
        {
            if (maxPrice == UNDEFINED_FILLTER)
            {
                if (MinimumNumOfRooms == UNDEFINED_FILLTER)
                {
                    if (MaximumNumOfRooms == UNDEFINED_FILLTER)
                    {
                        if (1 /*dateofevcation  == undefined*/)
                        {
                            printf("Apartment code: %d\nApartment address: %s\n Apartment price: %d\n", currentAprt->code,currentAprt->address,currentAprt->price);
                            printf("Number of rooms: %d\nPossible entry date: %s\nAdding date: %s",currentAprt->numOfRooms,currentAprt->enteryDate,currentAprt->addingDate);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //check date of evacuation criteria
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //check maximum number of rooms and date of evacuation criteria
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //check minimum number of rooms, maximum number of rooms and date of evacuation criteria
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //check max price, minimum number of rooms, maximum number of rooms and date of evacuation criteria
            }
            currentAprt = currentAprt->next;
        }
```

**MY QUESTION:**
**Is there any simple way to check if the user wrote a command with criteria, check it and go for the next criteria?
or the only way is to write it with if-else statements?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: you will have to show some code

Comment: If you have a static list of criteria, you can just join them up with `&&`: `if (min_rooms_ok(rooms) && max_rooms_ok(rooms) && price_ok(price))` instead of using `else` statements.

Comment: If you have a dynamic list of criteria, you probably want to describe them in some data-driven format and loop over them: `for (i=0; i!=num_criteria; ++i) { if (!meets(thingy, criteria[i])) return 0; } return 1;`

Comment: Trying to write anything less abstract and general without any idea of what your code looks like is pretty much impossible, but hopefully this will be enough to get you unblocked, or at least enough to get you to understand what you need in a [mcve] so we can answer you.

Comment: Think step-wise. Once the first criteria is met, take the results from that and move on to the second criteria, and finally after all criterias are met, display the result. `User Input |> filter query 1 |> filter query 2 |>| result`

Comment: Do you know about the `&&` operator of C ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch of course, but it seems a little complex and unreadable to gather all this conditions together.

Answer (score 1):

I find that many complex if-then trees can be greatly simplified by using early returns / early continue:

```
#define UNDEFINED_FILLTER -1

void loop_over_rooms() {
    for (; currentAprt != NULL; currentAprt = currentAprt->next) {
        if (maxPrice == UNDEFINED_FILLTER) { continue; }
        if (MinimumNumOfRooms == UNDEFINED_FILLTER) { continue; }
        if (MaximumNumOfRooms == UNDEFINED_FILLTER) { continue; }

        // At this point, we know fields are filled 
        printf(...);             
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about if the user asking for: "PRINT maxPrice 30000"? How can I ignore the maximun and minimum certiea and print out only the apartments that meet the price requirement?

Comment: I'm not going to write all your code for you. You asked how to simplify a complex if-then tree, and I showed one way to do that (there are others). It's still your job to adapt your code, and if you run into any other problems, ask a new question.